# Cell array matches common values excludes blank

Tags: arrays, excel, match

I have a list of name that are on one sheet and need to find the most common repeat name of that list.  The list spans for the entire month. Example:

```
10/1    James
10/2    Bill
10/3    Fred
10/4    Hank
etc...
```

On another sheet I have this in-cell array that finds the most common, BUT if the list has blanks, it returns an error.  Only when the list is full does it then give you an answer.

```
{=INDEX('Sept 18'!B$2:B$151,MODE(MATCH('Sept 18'!B$2:B$151,'Sept 18'!B$2:B$151,0)+{0,0})),"")}
```

Is there a way to make it always show a name and exclude the blanks as it goes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is data in **B2** through **B11** that may include blanks, then use the **array formula**:

```
=INDEX(B2:B21,MODE(IF(B2:B21<>"",MATCH(B2:B21,B2:B21,0))))
```

[image]

**Array formulas** must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.  If this is done correctly, the formula will appear with curly braces around it in the Formula Bar.

Comment: Thank you for helping me, but when i place that array in, i still get a "#N/A" error.  he is what i have in the cell.  

{=INDEX('Oct 18'!B$2:B$151,MODE(IF('Oct 18'!B$2:B$151<>"",MATCH('Oct 18'!B$2:B$151,'Oct 18'!B$2:B$151,0))))}

Comment: nevermind i have seen the "error" in my ways, thank you for the help.

Comment: @AmongTheShadows  Thank you for the feedback